# How to display DBNull int as blank

Tags: c#, sql

I am selecting information from a database of mostly strings, however I have a datatype of number which if that value in the db is null I would like it to display as blank in my grid.  I've tried reading the number in as a string but it is not working.

```
AccountUid = dr["ACCOUNT_UID"] == DBNull.Value ? null: Convert.ToInt32(dr["ACCOUNT_UID"])
```

I'm not sure what to put in where null is to get a db value of null to display as nothing.  AccountUid is an int?.

Comment: Have you tried `string.Empty`?

Comment: if your **AccountUid** is string then it gives error in **Convert.ToInt32(dr["ACCOUNT_UID"])** you have to get **dr["ACCOUNT_UID"]** without converting it to int

Comment: That won't work because there is no implicit conversion between string and int

Comment: What's the data type of `AccountUid`? Integers (or nullable integers) can't be "blank", that's up to the code that prints those values to the screen.

Comment: Updated original post.  Account Uid is of type int?

Comment: If `AccountUid` is `int?` then the code you posted should work. How are you displaying the data?

Comment: This is a problem in the grid, not how you populate the property. Can you show how you fill the grid or how you configure that column? What is the grid showing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I got it to work.  So I was close I just needed to add (int?) to null and it works now.

```
AccountUid = dr["ACCOUNT_UID"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(dr["ACCOUNT_UID"])
```